# Error: Twilio.Exceptions.AuthenticationException: 'Username can not be null'

Tags: c#

Ola!
Estou tentando criar uma aplicação Twilio em C#, peguei o código na documentação oficial. Instalei todos os pacotes que a documentação pedia, e tentei executar o app, mas aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

Code:

```
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;
using Twilio.Types;

TwilioClient.Init(
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("********"),
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("********")
);

var message = MessageResource.Create(
    from: new PhoneNumber("whatsapp:********"),
    to: new PhoneNumber("Whatsapp:********"),
    body: "Test"
);

Console.WriteLine("Message SID: ", message.Sid);
```

Error:

```
Unhandled exception. Twilio.Exceptions.AuthenticationException: Username can not be null
   at Twilio.TwilioClient.SetUsername(String username)
   at Twilio.TwilioClient.Init(String username, String password)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in 
line 5
```

Tentei implementar a linha de código que aparece na mensagem de erro, mas o erro continua lá.

Code:

```
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;
using Twilio.Types;

TwilioClient.Init(
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("*********"),
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("*********")
);

Twilio.TwilioClient.SetUsername(
    username: "*********@gmail.com"
);

Twilio.TwilioClient.Init(
    username: "*********@gmail.com", 
    password: "*********"
);

var message = MessageResource.Create(
    from: new PhoneNumber("whatsapp:*********"),
    to: new PhoneNumber("Whatsapp:*********"),
    body: "Teste"
);

Console.WriteLine("Message SID: ", message.Sid);
```

Algo importante de se frisar é que eu criei e configurei minha conta no Twilio, então está tudo certo

Comment: Traduza a pergunta ou utilize o SO em inglês.

Comment: Achei que estava usando o inglês, perdão...

Comment: Vou traduzi-la.

Comment: Ajustou as var de ambiente?

Comment: Sim, eu segui o passo a passo do vídeo oficial do Twilio: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1YBANe4DfiA

Comment: Tente verificar se elas estao retornando corretamente, pois parece que o problema está nessa parte onde `TwilioClient.Init` deve está recebendo `null`

Comment: coloca os valores de `GetEnvironmentVariable` em variáveis e verifique se tem valor, pode ser o nome da variável ou ela pode não estar setada corretamente

Answer (score 0):

Pelo exemplo que mostrou você está com um código correto, porém pode ser que a variável de ambiente utilizada para identificar a conta e o token está incorreta.

Normalmente para conseguir autenticar na API você deve usar os dados de ACCOUNT SID e AUTH TOKEN, disponíveis no console da Twilio e não e-mail e senha da conta.

Seria interessante colocar um log para verificar se as informações estão nas suas variáveis de ambiente.

Veja um exemplo de implementação:

```
    string accountSid = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
    string authToken = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");

    TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

    var message = MessageResource.Create(
        body: "This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?",
        from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("whatsapp:NUMERO_ORIGEM"),
        to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("whatsapp:NUMERO_DESTINO")
    );
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).